# OpenCV AdaptiveTreshold Error: blockSize % 2 == 1 && blockSize > 1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use adaptiveTreshold, but I get error regarding blockSize. I know it should be odd and > 0, it is set 11 but it still shows this error. What could be wrong?

```
treshold = 115
maxValue = 255 
adaptiveMethod = cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C
thresholdType = cv.THRESH_BINARY
blockSize = 11
C = 2
            
im = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, treshold, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C)
            
plt.imsave(save_path, im, cmap = 'gray')
```

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1675: error: (-215:Assertion failed) blockSize % 2 == 1 && blockSize > 1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold
```

Answer (score 3):

**What's wrong?**

The function expects an **odd** numbered kernel. But you have passed the variable `thresholdType = cv.THRESH_BINARY` in place of `blockSize`. Since the corresponding integer value of `cv.THRESH_BINARY` is `0`, this error is raised.

**What does the error mean?**

It means both the following conditions **must** be satisfied:

1. `blockSize` must be an **odd** number
2. `blockSize` must be greater than `1`

In other words, `blockSize` must be 3 or any odd number above 3.

**How to correct it?**

Remove the unwanted `treshold`:

`cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C)`

Answer (score 0):

[`adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3) does not take a `threshold` argument. Your call should be

```
im = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C)
```